# How can I select a textView as interest in another layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

This is my application , I have `3 layout` ... help me................... "

I have `10 button`  in my `first layout`  that the text of these button are `10 title` (title 1 ,..... title 10).... When I press one of them a text that relates to one of titles ( txt1 ,tx2 ........ or txt10 )is shown in second layout .................

imagine .... you press title 1 and then txt1 is shown and when you read , this txt is your interest ......... The main question is : I want to have another layout (3rd) with listview that when you are interested in for example txt1 from second layout, you press a button and the first item of listview will make and it's text is title 1 ... and when you run my app after a while you go to your interests and read txt1 that you had choosed it before ......

what can I do ????

Comment: post your code that you have tried

Comment: I made first and second layout well .... but for 3rd layout I have no idea so I didn't try it ...... please suggest me an idea

Comment: your question is not clear enough, try to describe again

Comment: simple .... I want when user read a textview if text is good and user be interested in , press a button and this text goes another layout ...... after a while user can find fast his interests in this way

Answer (score 0):

You simply create a public static ArrayList in your third Acitivity of your 3rd layout, where your list view exist. When you click a button in 2nd layout access the static arraylist of 3rd layout and add the text to it.

In 3rd Activity than create a ArrayAdapter object that use your static Arraylist. Use this Adapter with you ListView. Here is sample code

In 3rd Activity where you use your 3rd layout

```
Public static ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adaper;


ListView lv = (ListView) findViewbyId(R.id.you_list_view_id);
if(listData.size > 0)
{
      adaper = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listData);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In 2nd layout's activity you add item to data list, when button clicked,

```
   listData.add(text1);
```

This is sample code i didn't test. if you got any error let me know.